# mi virtual host me envia a el archivo index de bitnami

Tags: php, apache

quería que al acceder mivhost.com me diriguiera una carpeta en especifico
utilice esto en el bitnami-apps-vhosts.conf de bitnami

```
 <VirtualHost *:80>

DocumentRoot "C:/Bitnami/wampstack-7.1.17-0/apache2/htdocs/public"
ServerAdmin aaaaaaaaaaaaaaa@gmail.com
ServerName mivhost.com 
ServerAlias www.mivhost.com

<Directory C:/Bitnami/wampstack-7.1.17-0/apache2/htdocs/public>
    Options FollowSymlinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>

ErrorLog "C:/Bitnami/wampstack-7.1.17-0/apache2/htdocs/error_log"
CustomLog "C:/Bitnami/wampstack-7.1.17-0/apache2/htdocs/access_log" common
```

y agregue esto en el host de windows

```
127.0.0.1 mivhost.com
```

Answer (score 0):

¿Logras acceder con exito a tu virtual host?

El código que muestras esta algo incompleto. La etiqueta `<VirtualHost *:80>` nunca se cierra. Recuera que `DocumentRoot` debe apuntar a la carpeta raiz de tu aplicación, automáticamente buscara el archivo index.

Referencias:

- https://docs.bitnami.com/virtual-machine/components/apache/#how-to-configure-your-web-application-to-use-a-virtual-host

Comment: la La etiqueta <VirtualHost *:80> esta cerrada lo que pasa es  que me comi esa parte del codigo me pasa que meto mivirtual host en la barra de direcciones y me habre el archivo index de bitnami que esta en la carpeta htdocs en vez del index de mi carpeta public

Comment: Disculpa la demora.
Intenta haciendo toda la gerarquía de carpetas. No solo pongas la carpeta public, crea una carpeta `virtual_host\public_html` y apunta a esa. Aquí te dejo un link que lo explica muy bien. https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/como-configurar-virtual-host-de-apache-en-ubuntu-14-04-lts-es#paso-cuatro-%E2%80%94-crear-nuevos-archivos-virtual-host